# jQuery: $ as a parameter

Tags: jquery

I'm reading a book on JavaScript that's explaining how to use the MVC pattern with JavaScript applications. In this code, it's showing how to set up a controller. Can anyone explain why the jQuery dollar sign is passed as a parameter to the function in line3, and then why there's no dollar sign in front of (jQuery) in the last line?

```
var Controller = {};
// Use a anonymous function to enscapulate scope
(Controller.users = function($){
    var nameClick = function(){
        /* ... */
    };

    // Attach event listeners on page load
    $(function(){
        $("#view .name").click(nameClick);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Proper indentation may help you understand what is going on.

Comment: @KevinB if the final (jQuery) is in fact calling the function, shouldn't it be on its own line?

Comment: no, `(jQuery)` is passing `jQuery` as an argument to the function stored in `Controller.users`. You don't split this into two lines do you? `alert("Hello World!")`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no dollar sign in front of `jQuery` in the last line because the name of the variable that holds jQuery is `jQuery`, not `$jQuery`. It's passed immediately as `$` to avoid naming conflicts.

Comment: so is (jQuery); calling the anonymous function? please explain if you can. I'm a bit inexperienced (although I've read a few books on it)

Comment: @Michael: Yup! (It's not really anonymous, though; it's assigned to `Controller.users` too.)

Answer (score 3):

Simply put, it's ensuring nothing else is named `$` in that context.

The jQuery variable is named `jQuery`, `$` is a valid symbol in a variable name, and jQuery has used it to store the jQuery object.  The code above could easily be rewritten to use any other variable name instead of `$`

```
var Controller = {};
// Use a anonymous function to enscapulate scope
(Controller.users = function(myJQueryVariable){
    var nameClick = function(){
        /* ... */
    };

    // Attach event listeners on page load
    myJQueryVariable(function(){
        myJQueryVariable("#view .name").click(nameClick);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery being passed to the function is supplying the argument for $ in the function. In other words, to guarantee that the function understands that $ is the jQuery object, the jQuery full object name is passed instead of the $ shortcut. This helps in cases where other javascript libraries are in use and might compete for the $ assignment.